# pyspark - search for an column value inside hive array created by collect_list aggregation

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using one py spark data frame with one aggregated column using the collect_list and I have to search another data frame column value in that collect list column, I created a UDF which says like below but it keeps failing as a stage failure.

UDF:

```
def udf_test(arr,x)
if arr is None:
        return None
    if x is None:
        return None
    for e in arr:
        if e == None:
            return False
        elif (e == x):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

---

```
dataframe.filter(udf(col('array_column),col('value_column'))
```

The above step is failing. Before this step, everything is cached and working fine. The above step also contains a join using those two data frames.

Sample input Data:

```
df1:
id  page_ids (collect_list)
12  ['1001','1001','1002','1003']
13  ['2001','2002','2003','2004']

df2:
id page_id
12 '1002'
13 '4001'

df3 = df1 \
     .join(df2,on=df1['id'] == df2['id']) \
     .filter(udf(col(page_ids),col('page_id))
```

Comment: you need to get the rows where , data in col('value_column') is present in col('array_column),correct ??

Comment: yes, exactly right, but the uDF is not working and array contains giving me data mismatch error because column value is string and collect list is hive array.

Comment: pls post some input data

Comment: edit the post..

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be to use array_contains with expr function,

```
Let's say, array_column => pageid_list and value_column => pageid

from pyspark.sql.functions import expr,array_contains
df3.filter(F.expr("array_contains(pageid_list,pageid)")).show()
+---+--------------------+------+
| id|         pageid_list|pageid|
+---+--------------------+------+
| 12|[1001, 1001, 1002...|  1002|
+---+--------------------+------+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh, it works but why the sql expr works but not normal array_contains, just a curiosity

Comment: Array_contains works on a array and a value. If we try like, select(array_contains('pageid_id','pageid')), it considers value as string pageid and not it's column value. Also, if we try df.pageid instead, it will be column. In this , we need use a udf to map each column value.